# c# Use String format to read a string into an object

Tags: c#, string

I've created a string using

```
String.Format(IPAddressRangeFormat, StartIP, EndIP);
```

Now I need to read the string back into the StartIP and EndIP objects.

What's the easiest way to do so in c#?

THanks,
Li.

Comment: Can you please include more code. Having more context would help people understand your problem.

Comment: could you please post the content of your variables

Comment: What is the value of `IPAddressRangeFormat`? There's no general solution for this problem.

Comment: The code you posted does nothing, please post a complete sample that reproduces your problem setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this as the reverse of a String.Format is not deterministic.

Both :

```
String.Format( "{0}{1}", "123", "456" )
String.Format( "{0}{1}", "12", "3456" )
```

gives you `123456`. The machine won't just guess which one you want.

However there is a trickier way to do it, you do have regular expressions.

If you have :

```
String.Format ( "{0}-{1}",  StartIP, EndIP);
```

You could use an expression :

```
var matches = Regex.Match ( String.Format ( "{0}-{1}",  "127.0.0.1", "192.168.0.1"), "(?<startIP>.*)-(?<endIP>.*)" );
Console.WriteLine ( matches.Groups["startIP"].Value ); // 127.0.0.1
Console.WriteLine ( matches.Groups["endIP"].Value );   // 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Using Regex is a bit of an over-complication in this case. why not `String.Split('-')`?

Comment: You could for the example I have given. However that will only work for a few limited situations. For the general situation of reversing a Format String, this is exactly what a Regex match is designed to do. Without knowing the exact circumstances of the OP, it is the only way to handle all possibilities.

Comment: Plus, once you get over your fear of Regexes they aren't that complicated. Or rather, you can have simple regexes and you can have complex ones - depending on what you are trying to do. IMHO `(?<startIP>.*)-(?<endIP>.*)` is not a complicated regex and should not take any effort for a halfway competent coder to understand.

Comment: Aaargh! I didn't mean that to be directed at you. Don't take it personally. I'll get my coat...

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to have the separate type like `IPRange` where you will have 2 IP's in costructor and overriden `ToString()`. Th parse back you probably will need to implement custom logic in lets say static `Parse(string)` member.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to do called Parsing and it can't be performed by String.Format method.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your formatting for `IPAddressRangeFormat`, use ToString() ...then `string.Split(':')` ...replacing the ':' with whatever `char` you are using.

I would really need to see your format for `IPAddressRangeFormat` to provide a better answer.